# Formatting units like 3k2 ohm with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I use the `siunitx`-package to format my units. But in electronics, it is sometimes done that the value of a component, say a resistor, is written like

[image]

which means 3200 ohm.

Is there a possibility to do this with the `siunitx`-package, i.e. that following code generates above result? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \SI{3.2e3}{\ohm}
    % or
    \SI{3.2}{\kilo\ohm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious. Where is that a standard way of writing 3.2kOhm?

Comment: What is wrong with standard units? You must always comply with the SI standard, i.e wrote `SI{2.2}{\kilo\ohm}`.

Comment: It is not used in text, but it can be used in the circuit diagram and my professor is a huge fan of the notation. That's mainly the reason why I want to write it in this style.

Comment: @Mario, even on schemes should be used IS units. One of engineers task is spread standards, which make their product international understandable and usable. I know, how difficult is this for people, who grow up with imperial units ... but this should not be an excuse :-)

Comment: @Zarko this notation has been standard in electronics for a long time for a good practical reason. When component values are marked on physical objects (circuit boards, the components themselves, etc) in dirty conditions, a small "." can easily become invisible, but larger symbol like a letter is more likely to remain readable. It would create even more chances for mistakes to use one "standard" in printed documents and a different "standard" for markings on the device that the document refers to.

Comment: @alephzero's point also applies to circuit diagrams reproduced on old photocopiers,  let alone faxed; luckily the error would tend towards a too-large resistor, which is less liekly to cause a dangerous fault than a too-small one.  I've just looked at an old ANSI standard for circuit diagrams, from the 60s, and that doesn't use this approach.  But it's very common in practice, and we may want to reproduce things as written.  Less commonly it's also used with voltages (almost always 3V3 for 3.3~V)

Comment: @Zarko There is no such thing as "imperial units" for electronic circuit components. In fact there is no longer such a thing as "imperial units" at all, since the only country bone-headed enough to still use them is the USA (Britain converted to metric units nearly 50 years ago).

Comment: @alephzero, I mentioned it as an example. However, many (the most of them, actually ) draw electrical schemes on american way, not in standard way.

Comment: You usually don't see the ohm symbol just the 3k2

Comment: I have to agree with the previous comment. The unit is clear from the context. If you  see a resistor symbol 3k3 means 3300 ohms. Next to a capacitor 3n3 means 3300 pF. The size matters as well. For unities the correct expression is 0R5 or 0C5. Although I have seen 0F5 as well for 0.5F.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I nominate

```
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{3k2}{\ohm}
```

and

```
\textup{3k2}\,\si{\ohm}
```

as answers to your question. The `\textup` directive guarantees that the numbers will be typeset in upright mode even when the expression occurs in *italic* text.

That said, I can't see what could possibly be wrong with writing

```
\SI{3.2}{\kilo\ohm}
```

Finally, if you *really* want to go for something eye-catching (though definitely also at least mildly eccentric), I could suggest

```
\SI{32}{\hecto\ohm}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for \si and \SI macros
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{3k2}{\ohm}
\textup{3k2}\,\si{\ohm}
\SI{3.2}{\kilo\ohm}
\SI{32}{\hecto\ohm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\kohm[1]{\kohmaux#1\relax}
\def\kohmaux#1.#2\relax{\textup{#1}\SI{#2}[k]{\ohm}}
\begin{document}
\kohm{3.2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between this approach and `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{3k2}{\ohm}`?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I am no expert in `siunitx`, but it seems to me Mico's approach is to consider the `k` as part of the number, while this approach treats the `k` as a pre-unit.  But it also means I have to parse and add the leading `3` outside of `siunitx` (you see it as `\textup{`#1}` in the defn.)